# What am I forgetting in the loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm trying to create a `table` with **6 rows**, but I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong in the `for` loop.

```html
<script>
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');

    document.body.appendChild(table);
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      tbody.appendChild(tr); // makes only 1 row, but should make 6 rows
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a new row inside the loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){    
    tbody.appendChild( document.createElement('tr') ); 
}
```

Comment: Yep! :) Thank you buddy!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method to create a clone of `<TR>` element and append that.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){    
    tbody.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a good alternative way for me, without putting var tr cretion into the loop.